# Does libpg-java support passwordless login?

Tags: java, password, postgresql

The following command runs fine, that is, doesn't ask for a password, prints no warnings or errors, and simply provides a DB prompt:

```
$ psql -U dbuser dbname
psql (8.4.10)
Type "help" for help.

dbname=#
```

When trying to generate an ERD out of this DB with [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/) (running as the same host user), it doesn't work:

```
$ java -jar ~/schemaSpy.jar -dp /usr/share/java/postgresql.jar -t pgsql \
-host localhost -db dbname -u dbuser -o ~/db

Using database properties:
  [/[...]/schemaSpy.jar]/net/sourceforge/schemaspy/dbTypes/pgsql.properties

Failed to connect to database URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost/dbname]

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based
authentication, but no password was provided.
```

If I try with a blank password (`-p ''`), it instead prints:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for
user "dbuser"
```

**How do I run SchemaSpy on a PostgreSQL database with a DB user that has no password?**

I tried changing the `pg_hba.conf` settings to completely permissive, but it still doesn't work:

```
$ sudo grep ^local /etc/postgresql/*/main/pg_hba.conf
local   all         postgres                          ident
local   all         all                               trust
```

Comment: This seems quite off topic for Ask Ubuntu. Is your problem related to Ubuntu in any way?

Comment: `psql` and `libpg-java` are Ubuntu packages.

Comment: Yes, but it isn't really related to Ubuntu in any obvious way.

Comment: Maybe it should be migrated to SuperUser? I found a lot of references to similar questions on Google before I found a useful answer.

Comment: Not sure, it could be a good question for [dba.se].

Comment: I doubt it's technical enough to be worth mention on DBA, but perhaps on the more general-purpose SO in that case?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2381/discussion-between-octavian-damiean-and-l0b0)

Answer (score 8):

Found the answer related to a similar problem with pgAdmin III: Both programs (unlike `psql`) [establish **TCP/IP** connections](http://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/735) rather than Unix socket connections, so the relevant line in `/etc/postgresql/*/main/pg_hba.conf` is *this* one, which *will* result in a password prompt even if the password is empty.

```
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
```

To fix this, you have to trust connections from localhost, for example with the following line:

```
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
```

**and** reload the configuration:

```
sudo service postgresql reload
```

Now both SchemaSpy and pgAdmin should be able to connect.